# Product and quotient of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions

> Let $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ smooth functions on $\mathbb {R}$, prove that $fg$ and $\frac{f}{g}$ are smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$, where $g \not\equiv 0$.

Logically, they are smooth because if $f$ and $g$ are smooth on $\mathbb{R}$ that means they are $n$ times differentiable and each derivative is derivative. Therefore, from calculus, $f.g$ and $\frac{f}{g}$ are also $n$ times differentiable and each derivative is continuous. However, I am not sure about the formal proof.

My attempt:

1. Assuming that $f$ and $g$ are smooth on $\mathbb{R}$, we want to prove that $f.g$ is smooth. In order to do so, we should prove that $f.g$ is $n$ times differentiable and each derivative is continuous.

That’s true in the case of $n=1$. Let’s assume that when $f$ and $g$ are $n-1$ times differentiable then $f .g$ is $n-1$ times differentiable.

Now, we have

$(f. g)’=f’.g + g’. f$

$f,\ g,\ f’ \text{and} \ g’$ are $n-1$ times differentiable, so by the induction step $(f.g)’$ is $n-1$ times differentiable. Then $f.g$ is $n$ times differentiable and all of the derivatives are continuous, as desired.

2. We know that $\frac{f}{g}=f .\frac{1}{g}$, so by (1), if we prove that $\frac{1}{g}$ is $n$ times differentiable on $\mathbb{R} - \{g ^{-1}(0)\}$ whenever $g$ is $n$ times differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, we find that $\frac{f}{g}$ is smooth.

Assuming that if $g$ is $n-1$ times differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, then $\frac{1}{g}$ is $n-1$ times differentiable on $\mathbb{R} - \{g^{-1}(0)\}$, we obtain

$(\frac{1}{g})’= \frac{-g’}{g^2}$ is $n-1$ times differentiable on $\mathbb{R} - \{g^{-1}(0)\}$ because it is a quotient of two $n-1$ times differentiable functions.

As a result, $\frac{f}{g}$ is smooth.

Is my answer correct? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if $g\equiv 0?$

Comment: @zhw. Sorry, I am not sure that I got what you mean. Do you mean that I should put $\mathbb{R} - \{ g^{-1}(0)\}$ instead of $\mathbb{R} - \{ g(0)\}$?

Comment: The statement of the problem is wrong. $1$ and $0$ are smooth, but $1/0$ is defined nowhere.

Comment: @zhw. oh yes, you’re right. I should have written $g \not\equiv 0$. In that case, is the prof correct? Thank you!

Comment: You should assume $g$ is nowhere $0.$

Comment: @zhw. Ok, thank you so much.